# How to access CRUD operations of single db class instance without static methods

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, nosql

I'm new to NoSql and MongoDB. I'm using the MongoDB C# driver inside Visual Studio.
I've read in different places that it's preferable to have a single instance of your database class that maintains the connection(s) to keep everything thread safe and that it's generally a bad idea to use static classes for database CRUD operations.

At the start of my program I instantiate my database class which opens a connection. Within that class and also in derived classes I can perform CRUD operations. But now I'm in a different part of my solution (same namespace, different class) and I need to do read operations to check if a user exists. I also need to compose a new document that I then want to insert.

Now I'm in a situation where that's only possible by creating a new instance of the database class to access its CRUD methods. I want to avoid static CRUD methods (that could be accessed from other classes) because then the base class of my database connection also needs to be static. I cannot figure out how to approach this and what would be the recommended way.

From the MongoDB website:

> The MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads.
> http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/getting_started/quick_tour/

Does this mean I should create a new MongoClient everytime I need to acces the database in others parts of my program?

**UPDATE**

It seems I was a bit mistaken about the static properties and how they can be used. I now have it setup like this:

```
class Database
{
    const string MongoConnection = "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster.mongodb.net";
    public static MongoClient Client { get; set; }
    public static IMongoDatabase Directory { get; set; }
    public static IMongoCollection<User> Collection { get; set; }

    public Database()
    {
        Client = new MongoClient(MongoConnection);
        Directory= Client.GetDatabase("studentDB");
        Collection = Directory.GetCollection<User>("users");
    }

    public static void InsertNewUser(User user)
    {
        Collection.InsertOne(user);
    }

    public static bool EmailHasAccount(string email)
    {
        return Collection.Find(x => x.Email == email).FirstOrDefault() == null ? false : true;
    }

    public static User RetrieveUserAccount(string email)
    {
        return Collection.Find(x => x.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public User(string name, string email)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

And in my main program I can use it like this:

```
    var db = new Database();
    var user = new User("myName", "email@address");

    Database.InsertNewUser(user);

    Console.WriteLine(Database.EmailHasAccount("email@address")); // returns true
    Console.WriteLine(Database.RetrieveUserAccount("email@address").Name); // returns "myName"
```

That's exactly what I was looking for. What would be the best way to handle multiple collections? Would it be safe to change the Collection property or is it better to create separate properties? Is a Generic even possible?

Comment: `then the base class of my database connection also needs to be static.`  You can have static fields/properties/methods on non static types.  I usually create a new connection only when I go to use that connection, and close it after.  If you want that single instance, couldn't you make it a singleton?  You can have access to the instance via  a static property, but its methods and the instance itself are not static.

Comment: The problem with static methods is that they cannot acces instance variables like the client object that the constructor of my class creates with = new MongoClient() or the client.GetDatabase() object. I have seen a couple of Singleton examples but was warned not to use Singleton because of difficulty with testing?

Comment: The difficulty comes when unit testing, since you cannot swap out the singleton reference for a self contained testing reference.  In the case of your database, the singleton would refer to your db class, and you would not be able to swap in an in-memory db for the unit tests.  Just make a static property from the main class you have,  the static property would be typed to the interface for your db class.  Assign when you create the db instance.  Then you can access it from wherever.  You are accessing the class via a static property, it does not make the class or any of its methods static.